# why the javascript variable doesn't change among function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my problem with the following javascript function:

```
function ValidateDates() {

var valid = false;
birthD = $("#cp1_txtBirthDate").val();
initialD = $("#cp1_txtInitialDate").val();
var regexp = new RegExp("^([1-9]|(0|1|2)[0-9]|30)(/)([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9])(/)((20|19|18)[0-9]{2})$");

if (birthD != "__/__/____" && initialD != "__/__/____") {
    if (regexp.test(initialD) && regexp.test(birthD)) {

        $.get("ValidateDates.aspx?BirthD=" + birthD + "&InitialD=" + initialD, function (data) {
            if (data == 0) {
                valid = true;

                $("#Dates_span").html("");
            }

            else {
                $("#Dates_span").html("*" + data);
                valid = false;

            }

        });

    }
}

return valid;
}
```

here when i check the variable valid i found it "false" even if its true, because the initial for it is false from the beginning of function so how to solve it and what is wrong?

Comment: You have not described clearly what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're doing an asynchronous call, you can't return a value like that.  Instead, you should pass in a callback:

```
function ValidateDates(callback) {

    var valid = false;
    birthD = $("#cp1_txtBirthDate").val();
    initialD = $("#cp1_txtInitialDate").val();
    var regexp = new RegExp("^([1-9]|(0|1|2)[0-9]|30)(/)([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9])(/)((20|19|18)[0-9]{2})$");

    if (birthD != "__/__/____" && initialD != "__/__/____") {
        if (regexp.test(initialD) && regexp.test(birthD)) {

            $.get("ValidateDates.aspx?BirthD=" + birthD + "&InitialD=" + initialD, function(data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    valid = true;

                    $("#Dates_span").html("");
                }

                else {
                    $("#Dates_span").html("*" + data);
                    valid = false;

                }
                callback(valid);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then, call it like:

```
ValidateDates(function(isValid)
{
   // Do something with isValid
});
```

Comment: sorry but i am stuck with something, i want the returned value to use it in if condition with other function like this :if (Page_ClientValidate() && ValidateName() && ValidNull && ValidateDates) so how to deal with this?

Comment: If ValidateDates is the only async one, you can just put the others inside the function.  Otherwise, you can chain the async calls using multiple functions.

Comment: how to make chain because i have many ajax calls for validation and i am using validatePage function that contains all validation to check before submit the page as "client side function" and "has returned value true or false

Comment: @speciallife, you could make a server-side wrapper function to do all the validation in one AJAX call.  Alternatively, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995529/how-to-chain-ajax-requests).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that `$.get` is an asynchronous call, what that means is that the function doesn't wait until the result is returned from `$.get` call. It just makes the call and continues execution - so `valid = true` is set long after `false` has been returned.