# How to keep "response" out of FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am just trying FB JS api and want to know whether or how I can still use "response" out of FB.api. For example:

```
var picture;
FB.api('/me/picture?width=180&height=180', function (response) {
            picture = response.data.url;
            console.log(picture);
});
alert(picture);
```

The above code will show "undefined" in alert window.

Is there a way to use "response.data.url" out of FB.api?

Thanks

Update:
Here is the big picture: I need retrieve some information from FB user account, such as /me/name, /me/address/city, /me/picture.data.url and group them together and then send the information to server through AJAX.

```
var name;
var city;
var picture;

FB.api('/me', function (response) {
    name = response.name;
    FB.api('/me/address', function (adrresponse) {
        city = adrresponse.city;
    }
    FB.api('/me/picture', function (imgresponse) {
        picture = imgresponse.data.url;
    }
    //since FB API is async, the following is not correct!!!
    var params = "name="+name+"&city="+city+"&picture="+picture;

    //send out through AJAX.
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);
}
```

Is there a better way to finish the above job?

Update 2:
The best way is to use fields expansion
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#fieldexpansion, as shown by the answer of this question.
Thanks
Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `picture` variable is not populated at the time that the alert fires. It will only be populated after the `FB.api` callback completes.

```
var picture;
FB.api('/me/picture?width=180&height=180', function (response) {
            picture = response.data.url;
            // this would work correctly
            alert(picture);
});
```

What are you attempting to do with the `picture` variable? Perhaps you should call a function do something with the picture inside your callback:

```
var picture;
FB.api('/me/picture?width=180&height=180', function (response) {
            picture = response.data.url;
            doSomethingWithPicture(picture);
});
```

### Update

The simple way to achieve what you are after is this:

```
FB.api('/me', function (response) {
  var name = response.name;
  FB.api('/me/address', function (adrresponse) {
    var city = adrresponse.city;
      FB.api('/me/picture', function (imgresponse) {
         var picture = imgresponse.data.url;
         doAjax(name, city, picture);
      }
  }
}

function doAjax(name, city, picture) {
   //since FB API is async, the following is not correct!!!
   var params = "name="+name+"&city="+city+"&picture="+picture;

   //send out through AJAX.
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   http.open("POST", url, true);
}
```

However, this is not ideal as you have to wait for `/me/address` before you can call `/me/picture`.

Here are some other options

1. you need to call `/me` first.
2. you fire off both api calls and execute code when the both complete

Ways to accomplish #2

- You could then use a promise library to chain the `/me/address` and `/me/picture`/. See: https://github.com/kriskowal/q or https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ to get started
- Call a callback after each that conditionally fires the ajax if both address and picture are set
- I am sure there are a number of other ways:

  - [How to chain ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995529/how-to-chain-ajax-requests)
  - [How to chain ajax calls using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612894/how-to-chain-ajax-calls-using-jquery)

### Update #2

This is the best way to accomplish what you are after (no additional callbacks required)

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'picture', 'address']}, function(response) {
    // response will now have everything you need
    console.log(response);
});
```

I did not give this answer originally as it was not the topic of the question which seemed to be scoping.

Comment: my plan is to pass this profile picture url (along with "email", "name", etc. ) to server througth AJAX. I can have "name" and "email" easily. But I cannot get the  picture url.

Comment: Suppose I am inside "FB.api('/me', function(response) { }". why we cannot just have reponse.picture.data.url, instead of having a nested "FB.api('/me/picture?width=180&height=180', function (response) {}" inside?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your last question. I am a little confused

Comment: make sure you understand what "asynchronous" means, it´s important in javascript

Comment: I have updated the question, please take a look. Thanks, Derek.

Comment: I find fields expansion may be a better choice.